# Custom request attribute aren't same name of the model attributes, using node.js node-restful lib

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mongoose

My Node.js application is a RESTful API.
My User Schema has two attributes: app and user_id.
To better semantic use of API, client applications must set to a POST request to create a new User, the header Application(app attribute on User model) and id param on application/json body from POST /users request.

But, I need that the `id` param from request be the `user_id` param and `Application` header from request be the `app` attribute on my User model. This is possible? How?

I'm using node-restful lib, but I not found a doc about complex routing params, not have a this custom params doc.

My model attributes isn't the same of the client applications request input.

Now, I have:

/routes/api.js

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

// User Routes
User.methods(['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']);
User.register(router, '/users');

// Return router
module.exports = router;
```

/models/user.js

```
// Dependencies
var restful = require('node-restful');
var mongoose = restful.mongoose;

// Schema
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    app: String,
    user_id: Number
});

// Return Model
module.exports = restful.model('Users', UserSchema);
```